# jQuery if($(element).find(selector)) stops script on failure to find

Tags: jquery

as part of a script i am working on i have the following:

```
loop
if($(element).find(selector))
{ do stuff }
else
{ do other stuff }
/loop
```

The idea is that there are two versions of the elements getting looped and I need to distinguish between them (based on content) to determine which actions to take.

This works great if find is successful.  If it is not, then the script has a fatal error.

I can't find any documentation on what happens when find fails.  How do I make this work?

Comment: an empty result from `find` should not break your code. Could you check with Firebug or the Webkit console and supply both an exception and the code on the line that throws it?

Comment: could you post the real code you are using?

Comment: I never did get an error statement from firebug, but apparently it was entering the if and then faulting when trying to use the element defined by the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
if($(element).find(selector).length > 0)
{ do stuff }
```

It's a little longer, but ought to work.

Looks to me like your original find test always evaluates to true.  Testing the length gets you a boolean result to evaluate.

Comment: Ohh! but you could save ***One Character!!!*** :P `(!$("#first").find("img").length)` and reverse the stuffs

Comment: I'll keep my character and the clarity I get from it :)